# Python Regular Expression--extracting coordinates

Tags: python, regex

I've got a question about regular expressions in Python. I'm working on a project for which I have to parse a bunch of huge text files and extract certain parts of them into a spreadsheet. One part of it is a bunch of lot sizes, expressed in the form `"NUMBERxNUMBERxNUMBER..."`. They're stored in the middle of a much bigger line, like this:

```
Spring st. , No. 208, 18.9x42.2x49x10x8x100. 'John S. Giles, exr. to Herman Goodstein, W. D. . 11,100
```

I'm trying to design a regular expression that would yield:

```
18.9x42.2x49x10x8x100
```

But I'm not quite sure where to start. What would be the best way to design an expression of this type, where there can be any number of numbers (with decimal points), separated by x? Whitespace would stop the analysis.
Thank you in advance for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''Spring st. , No. 208, 18.9x42.2x49x10x8x100. 'John S. Giles, exr. to Herman Goodstein, W. D. . 11,100'''
>>> re.search('(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?x)+\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(22, 43), match='18.9x42.2x49x10x8x100'>
>>> _.group(0)
'18.9x42.2x49x10x8x100'
```

The regular expression consists of `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` twice which just is a number of digits optionally followed by a dot with more digits. We do this to prevent a trailing dot. The expression searches for this “number part” followed by an `x` as often as possible and then requires a final “number part”.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks! Forgot to escape the dot—fixed!